# Mongoengine chaining filter() and ReferenceField() causes "TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable"

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, mongoengine

Having these 2 MongoEngine Documents:

```
class A(Document):
    a = StringField()

class B(Document):
    b = StringField()
    boolfield = BooleanField(default=False)
    ref = ReferenceField(A)
```

I'd like first to `filter()` on a specific A object, and then, from the first query, `filter()` on the BooleanField. But these lines cause an error:

```
a_objects = A.objects(a='test') # OK
query = B.objects(ref__in=a_objects) # OK
query2 = query.filter(boolfield=True) # FAILS
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: 'Collection' object is not callable. If you meant to call the '__deepcopy__' method on a 'Collection' object it is failing because no such method exists.
```

See the full code and traceback here: https://gist.github.com/nferrari/4962245

Thanks!

Comment: What version of mongoengine and pymongo?

Comment: mongoengine 0.7.8, pymongo 2.4.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems that querying reference fields can't be chained in 0.7.8 - so for the time being please use a dictionary and then pass in as kwargs as a work round eg:

```
    a_objects = A.objects(a='test')
    query_dict = {'ref__in': a_objects}
    query_dict['boolfield'] = True
    self.assertEquals(B.objects(**query_dict).count(), 1)
```

I have added: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/234 to be fixed in 0.8

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Indeed, problem is solved by using a dict and passing kwargs.